# Angularjs Project run localmachine

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wanna run [this project](https://github.com/ranjithprabhuk/Angular-Bootstrap-Dashboard) using `Node.js`. I have already installed it. But I don't know how to run it in my local system. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) for running a simple http server, run the server in the folder of the project (i.e. the folder containing index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install a simple http-server by following command

```
npm install -g http-server
```

go to project main folder where `index.html` exists and run command

```
http-server
```

You can start your project at `locathost:8080`